# Reading data from a serial input stream

Tags: java, arduino

I'm writing a program that communicates with an Arduino over the serial port, which then returns a `String` (length 70, ending in *#). In my main I want to read this `String`, how can I do that?

```java
public static synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
     if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
         try {
             String inputLine=input.readLine();
             if (inputLine.endsWith("*#")){

                read = inputLine;
             }
             System.out.println(inputLine);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             System.err.println(e.toString());
         } 
     }
}
```

The system.out is returning the string, but when I print 'read' in my main it comes out with garbage (a pointer to my input buffer I think). read is a static string, does the fact this is static mean I cannot change its value?

Comment: In this case, static means the string is global. There may be many (hypothetically) serial line reader(s) and that would read one line at a time. Also, check that inputLine is actually 70 characters? And maybe trim the line after readLine.

Comment: `String inputLine=input.readLine();` what is `input`?

Comment: If you are using multiple threads with static variables, you might want to put in some synchronized blocks to ensure only one thread is reading or writing to the static variable at a time.

Comment: You should show expected and actual outputs in your question

Comment: my input is a serial input on com3, system out is printing the right thing, its just im not sure how to pass this into main, because using this static variable hasnt worked

Comment: I don't see the rest of your code, but your sure you've got the right baud rate/bit parity?